# Law of Total Probability and inclusion exclusion principle for non-disjoint sets

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to apply the Law of Total Probability for non-disjoint sets. For example, given two non-disjoint sets $B_1$ and $B_2$ and an event $A$, I know that the following is true:

If $B_1 \cup B_2 = \Omega$ then:

$P(A) = P(B_1 - B_2)P(A|B_1-B_2) + P(B_2 - B_1)P(A|B_2-B_1) + P(B_1 \cap B_2)P(A|B_1 \cap B_2)$

However, is the following true?

$P(A) = P(B_1) P(A|B_1) + P(B_2)P(A|B_2) - P(B_1 \cap B_2)P(A|B_1 \cap B_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\P{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}$Why, certainly.

$$\begin{align}\P(A) &= \P(A\cap (B_1\cup (B_2\setminus B_1)) \\[1ex] &= \P((A\cap B_1)\cup(A\cap B_2)\setminus (A\cap B_1)) \\[1ex] &= \P(A\cap B_1)+\P(A\cap B_2)-\P(A\cap B_1\cap B_2)\\[2ex] &=~\P(A\mid B_1)\P(B_1)+\P(A\mid B_2)\P(B_2)-\P(A\mid B_1\cap B_2)\P(B_1\cap B_2) \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes...

$P(A\cap B_1) = P(B_1)P(A|B_1)$ and likewise $P(A\cap B_2) = P(B_2)P(A|B_2)$ and $P(A\cap B_2\cap B1) = P(B_2\cap B_1)P(A|B_2\cap B_1)$. Either B_1, B_2 or both events happen, therefore $P(A) = P(A|B_1)P(B_1)+P(A|B_2)P(B_2)-P(A|B_1\cap B_2)P(B_1 \cap B_2).$

But...

There is an exception in the case when $P(B_1)=0$ or $P(B_2)=0$ or $P(B_1 \cap B_2)=0$. Then the conditional probability is undefined.